# Can Nowhere Man be considered internally consistent at all?

Tags: nowhere-man

I loved Nowhere Man, but if we accept the explanation at the end:

> That Thomas Veil was actually sleeper agent programmed to think that he was someone else, a la Total Recall

How can this be reconciled with earlier episodes, particularly the one with Dean Stockwell, which features, apparently,

> someone else who'd had their life erased. Was he programmed too?

I love the show, but it seems to me that they were just having fun creating an anthology show with no internal consistency. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

**I believe that Nowhere Man is internally consistent, but that such consistency has little context or meaning in a show that focuses on the philosophical problems of illusion versus reality.**

While it is true that [Nowhere Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_Man_%28TV_series%29)'s **Thomas Veil** ran into several other "erased" victims, there is no guarantee that those victims were or weren't who they say they were.

That's the beauty of the show.  The show obviously takes a lot from [The Prisoner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner), which also featured an epically powerful, evil yet mysterious, mind control-focused organization.

In both series the organizations behind the conspiracies would go to almost any lengths, sometimes using cutting edge mind control techniques, to achieve their goals and maintain their secrecy.

Within the context of a powerful organization with near sci-fi mind control and social engineering techniques almost anything is possible.  Because humans can be programmed, any fake event can be staged like it's a real event.

In the end the point is that it's never clear what is truly real about Thomas Veil's life and what is an illusion, and that's probably how it would have stayed until the last episode had the series continued.

Too bad it didn't make it to a second season. :(

Comment: So, I think the answer to my question is yes...and also no.

Answer (score 1):

Chris -

Technically, it is indeed consistent. If that is what happened to Veil, then it's safe to assume that it also happen to Dean Stockwell's character; if it's something they've done to multiple people - it's not impossible that they have interwoven these people's stories. This would also serve to "self confirm" the stories; Dean confirm's Veil's fake story, Veil confirms Dean's fake story. It certainly is a far out premise, but it was a far out show! And personally, I live far out...